# iPhone Safari default state for JavaScript enabled

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile-safari

I'm testing various websites with newer iPhones, and noticing that the JavaScript enabled settings for Safari are defaulted to OFF. I'm surprised to see this, as the majority of websites barely work without JavaScript enabled, but I am finding very little information about this.

One person says they think the default doesn't get set to OFF until the first time you actually go into the settings for the first time.

Wondering if anyone has a definitive explanation regarding Safari JavaScript enabled settings in iOS 8+.

Comment: JavaScript works on my IPhones all the times (I have used several IPhones). I just checked my Safari settings and when I went to the settings JavaScript was set to be off. I guess it is indeed turned off when you go to the settings page for the first time

Comment: Out of curiosity - had JavaScript been working prior to you changing the settings - then when you accessed the settings, JavaScript became disabled?

Comment: it worked prior to the change and stopped working after it.